# C++ Functor Callback Setup

Tags: c++, callback, handler, functor

Im following Lars Haendel's [Functor tutorial](http://www.newty.de/fpt/functor.html#chapter4) on newty.de to setup a callback system. I am a bit confused however and I am hoping someone can assist me.

Here is my Functor template

```
#include <igameevents.h>

// Abstract Base Class (Functor)
class TBaseCallback
{
public:

    // two possible functions to call member function. virtual cause derived
    // classes will use a pointer to an object and a pointer to a member function
    // to make the function call
    virtual void operator()(IGameEvent *pEvent){};  // call using operator
    virtual void Call(IGameEvent *pEvent) {};       // call using function
};


// Derived Template Class
template <class TClass> class TEventCallback : public TBaseCallback
{
private:

    void (TClass::*funcPtr)(IGameEvent*);       // pointer to member function
    TClass* thisPtr;                            // pointer to object

public:

    // constructor - takes pointer to an object and pointer to a member and stores them in two private variables
    TEventCallback(TClass* _thisPtr, void(TClass::*_funcPtr)(const char*))
    { thisPtr = _thisPtr;  funcPtr=_funcPtr; };

    // override operator "()"
    virtual void operator()(IGameEvent *pEvent)
    { (*thisPtr.*funcPtr)(pEvent); };           // execute member function

    // override function "Call"
    virtual void Call(IGameEvent *pEvent)
    { (*thisPtr.*funcPtr)(pEvent); };           // execute member function
};
```

What I want to do is basically allow other .dlls to use my HookGameEvent() function, and when a Game Event is called, I can run through a vector||list of my hooks, check if the event name matches, then execute the callbacks as needed. What is confusing me though is how I can store the callback in my HookEvent struct which looks like this.

```
std::vector<EventHook*> m_EventHooks;

struct EventHook
{
    char *name;
    EventHookMode mode;
    //TEventCallback<IGameEvent*> pEventCallback;
};
```

I have it commented out for now, but im sure its obvious what im confused on and where I am screwing up. If anyone can provide any assistance it would be much appreciated.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice that your function pointer in the TEventCallback class is defined with a (const char *) parameter, but you're calling it with an (IGameEvent *) in the code.

Comment: Which points out the value of typedef-ing function types. @Brett: if you're dealing with error messages, it would be very useful to us if you included them in your question. If the code is failing to achieve what you want for other reasons, it would also be helpful for you to tell us those. Remember, tell us what you want to happen and what actually happens, otherwise we're just guessing.

Comment: The issue I was having was with how to put it in the struct, the (const char*) was just left over from when I was using that tutorial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most people don't understand inheritance. Generally, derived classes are implementation details. The only time you utter their names are to construct them. Furthermore, virtual functions in a base should be private and pure, and should be completely inaccessible in derived classes, it's a design bug in C++ that this isn't enforced.

```
struct TBaseCallback
    void operator()(IGameEvent *pEvent) { _Call(pEvent); }; 
    void Exec(IGameEvent *pEvent) { _Call(PEvent); }
private:
    virtual void _Call(IGameEvent *pEvent)=0;
};

struct EventHook
{
    char *name;
    EventHookMode mode;
    TBaseCallback *p;
    void dispatch(char *msg; IGameEvent *e) const { 
      if(strcmp(msg,name)==0) p->Exec(e); 
   }
};
```

With this design, it doesn't make any difference what is in classes derived from TBaseCallback, and nor should it. Only the abstraction should ever be publically visible. In normal code this is hard to enforce .. when you're using DLLs to get the derived classes it is absolutely mandatory because the set of derived classes is open/arbitrary/infinite/indeterminate (take your pick).

BTW: when you push this to more complex abstractions you will soon discover why Object Orientation is a broken concept. With DLL loaded derived classes, you simply **cannot** cheat with dynamic_cast switches (because they're closed/specific/finite/determinate).

Answer (score 0):

The class that is going to do the callbacks should hold a list of Functor objects to be called. These would be your

```
std::vector<EventHook*> m_EventHooks;
```

Now the EventHook should have a virtual function:

```
struct EventHook
{
    ...
    virtual void notifyMe();
}
```

Then everyone that is interested in getting notified will create his own implementation of the hook:

```
struct MyEventHook : public EventHook
{
    virtual void notifyMe() { ... whatever I want to do in that case ... }
}
```

Through the wonders of polymorphism, when you then iterate over all elements of your m_EventHooks container and call `notifyMe()` for those, the correct class' version will be called.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I see (and there could very well be others) is that in `pEventCallback`'s type, the template parameter should be a class type but is actually a pointer type. One fix (without limiting what types the callback wraps) is to use the base type:

```
struct EventHook
{
    char *name;
    EventHookMode mode;
    TBaseCallback* pCallback;
};
```

If there's more to `TEventCallback`'s API, and it needs to be accessible through an `EventHook`, you should move the code in `TEventCallback` that deals with an object and its method into a separate subclass.

```
// Example EventCallback that takes other args
class EventCallback : public TBaseCallback {
public:
    EventCallback();
    EventCallback(const EventArgs& evtArgs);
    // EventCallback specific methods ...
    virtual EventArgs& args();
    virtual const EventArgs& args() const;
}

/* TReturn allows for calling methods with a non-void return. Return value is ignored. 
 */
template <class TClass, typename TReturn = void> 
class TMethodCallback : public EventCallback
{
private:
    typedef TReturn (TClass::*TMeth)(IGameEvent*);
    TMeth funcPtr;       // pointer to member function
    TClass* thisPtr;                            // pointer to object

public:

    // constructor - takes pointer to an object and pointer to a member and stores them in two private variables
    TMethodCallback(TClass* _thisPtr, TMeth _funcPtr)
    { thisPtr = _thisPtr;  funcPtr=_funcPtr; };

    // override operator "()"
    virtual void operator()(IGameEvent *pEvent)
    { (*thisPtr.*funcPtr)(pEvent); };           // execute member function

    // override function "Call"
    virtual void Call(IGameEvent *pEvent)
    { (*thisPtr.*funcPtr)(pEvent); };           // execute member function
};
```

## Off-Topic

You might as well make the default implementation of `TBaseCallback::Call` call `TBaseCallback::operator()`.

```
void TBaseCallback::Call(IGameEvent *pEvent) { this->operator()(pEvent); };
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this seems to cover all the issues I was having. One question is though, basically when another plugin uses mine to create a hook, here is how it looks atm EventHookError HookEvent( const char *name, void *thisptr, void *callback, EventHookMode mode = EventHookMode_Post ); If the callback in the struct is a TBaseCallback, then it isn't going to be taken the class/funcPtr so I won't actually be able to store the callback there will I?

Comment: The API client would be responsible for creating the callback object. The prototype for `HookEvent` would be `EventHookError HookEvent( const char *name, TBaseCallback *pCallback, EventHookMode mode = EventHookMode_Post)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be getting a complicated compiler error because you are using T* instead of T in your template instantiation.

Try this:

```
struct EventHook
{
    char *name;
    EventHookMode mode;
    TEventCallback<IGameEvent> pEventCallback;
};
```

should compile, if that what you want.